# h2 VIEW has problems with correct SELECT statement

Tags: sql, h2

I am working on an accounting system, backed by an h2 database.  I have a number of views to pull together data from the `ACCOUNTS`, `TRANSACTIONS` and `TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS` tables.

**Problem, in a nutshell**

Although I have a `SELECT` statement which produces exactly the data I need to see in my `VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA` view, when I use that `SELECT` inside `CREATE VIEW VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA` and then go `SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA`, h2 tells me that one of the columns in it can't be found.  How can h2 be completely happy with the 'naked' `SELECT` statement, but then not happy once it's packaged into a `CREATE VIEW` statement?

I apologise for the length of this post, but the `SELECT` statement is of necessity rather long and complex, and there is necessary background information.  The post contains all the SQL needed to construct a small test database, for those who are interested.

**Background**

A template transaction is a way of storing frequently-used transactions in 'prototype' form: the only requirement for a template transaction is that it have a narration.  Date, amounts, accounts etc are all optional.

An account may have associated with it a template transaction which can be instantiated automatically when the account is reconciled.  This is very handy for credit card accounts, for example.

Naturally, the 'legs' for a template transaction are stored in a separate table from that which stores the header information.

So, we have the following tables and view (naturally, simplified from the real thing):

```
ACCOUNTS
ID   NAME         PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID   CURRENCY_ID
-------------------------------------------------
95   account0     null                1
122  account1     47                  0
178  foo bar      35                  0

TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS
ID   NARRATION
--------------
32   template0
35   template1
47   template2

TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS
ID   HEAD_TABLE_ID   ACCOUNT_ID   AMOUNT
----------------------------------------
23   32              95           null
74   35              178          500
75   35              null         -500

VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA
HEAD_ID   NARRATION   LEG_ID   ACCOUNT_ID   AMOUNT   CURRENCY_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------
23        template0   23       95           null     1
35        template1   74       178          500      0
35        template1   75       null         -500     null
47        template2   null     null         null     null
```

Here is the code for the above:

```
CREATE TABLE TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   NARRATION VARCHAR NOT NULL DEFAULT ' '
);

CREATE TABLE CURRENCIES(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR DEFAULT ''
);

CREATE TABLE ACCOUNTS(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   NAME VARCHAR DEFAULT '',
   PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID BIGINT,
   CURRENCY_ID BIGINT NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ACCOUNTS_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY(CURRENCY_ID) REFERENCES CURRENCIES(ID);   
ALTER TABLE ACCOUNTS ADD CONSTRAINT ACCOUNTS_FK_3 FOREIGN KEY(PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID) REFERENCES TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS(ID);

CREATE TABLE TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS(
   ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   HEAD_TABLE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL,
   ACCOUNT_ID BIGINT DEFAULT NULL,
   AMOUNT INT DEFAULT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ADD CONSTRAINT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS_FK_1 FOREIGN KEY(HEAD_TABLE_ID) REFERENCES TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS(ID);
ALTER TABLE TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ADD CONSTRAINT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS_FK_2 FOREIGN KEY(ACCOUNT_ID) REFERENCES ACCOUNTS(ID);

CREATE VIEW VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA AS (SELECT
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID     AS HEAD_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.NARRATION,

   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ID     AS LEG_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.AMOUNT,
   ACCOUNTS.CURRENCY_ID
   FROM (TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.HEAD_TABLE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID)
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNTS.ID
);

INSERT INTO CURRENCIES (ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (0, 'currency0');
INSERT INTO CURRENCIES (ID, DESCRIPTION) VALUES (1, 'currency1');
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS (ID, NARRATION) VALUES (32, 'template0');
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS (ID, NARRATION) VALUES (35, 'template1');
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS (ID, NARRATION) VALUES (47, 'template2');
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (ID, NAME, PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID, CURRENCY_ID) VALUES (95, 'account0', null, 1);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (ID, NAME, PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID, CURRENCY_ID) VALUES (122, 'account1', 47, 0);
INSERT INTO ACCOUNTS (ID, NAME, PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID, CURRENCY_ID) VALUES (178, 'foo bar', 35, 0);
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS (ID, HEAD_TABLE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (23, 32, 95, null);
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS (ID, HEAD_TABLE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (74, 35, 178, 500);
INSERT INTO TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS (ID, HEAD_TABLE_ID, ACCOUNT_ID, AMOUNT) VALUES (75, 35, null, -500);
```

This has been working fine in the production database for some time.  Now I need to add a boolean column, `IS_PAYER`, to the view, which will be `TRUE` for any template transactions whose IDs are in `ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID`.  As stated above, I have a `SELECT` statement which does exactly what I want:

```
HEAD_ID   NARRATION   LEG_ID   ACCOUNT_ID   AMOUNT   CURRENCY_ID   IS_PAYER
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
32        template0   23       95           null     1             FALSE
35        template1   74       178          500      0             TRUE
35        template1   75       null         -500     null          TRUE
47        template2   null     null         null     null          TRUE

SELECT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID     AS HEAD_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.NARRATION,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ID     AS LEG_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.AMOUNT,
   ACCOUNTS.CURRENCY_ID,
   IS_PAYER
FROM (
   (TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.HEAD_TABLE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNTS.ID)
JOIN
   (SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, (CASE WHEN PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS IS_PAYER FROM 
      (SELECT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID AS TEMPLATE_ID, ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID AS PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID FROM 
          ACCOUNTS RIGHT JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS ON ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID =TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID))
ON TEMPLATE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID
```

but when I do this:

```
DROP VIEW VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA;
CREATE VIEW VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA AS (SELECT
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID     AS HEAD_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.NARRATION,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ID     AS LEG_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.AMOUNT,
   ACCOUNTS.CURRENCY_ID,
   IS_PAYER
FROM (
   (TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.HEAD_TABLE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNTS.ID)
JOIN
   (SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, (CASE WHEN PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS IS_PAYER FROM 
      (SELECT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID AS TEMPLATE_ID, ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID AS PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID FROM 
          ACCOUNTS RIGHT JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS ON ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID =TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID))
ON TEMPLATE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID
);
```

and then go `SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA` it tells me `TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID not found`.

I really don't understand why my original view was acceptable, and my new `SELECT` is too, but my new `CREATE VIEW` isn't!  I don't do a lot in SQL, and the error message is not exactly helpful, and I really don't know where to go with this one.

Can any kind folks point me in the direction of a solution?

Comment: Please post error messages.

Comment: When I go `SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA` h2 tells me `View "PUBLIC.VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA" is invalid: "Column ""TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID"" not found [42122-167]"; SQL statement:
SELECT * FROM VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA [90109-167] 90109/90109`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem are the parentheses that you are using in your `JOIN` clauses. The SELECT on the view will work as soon as you remove them:

```
CREATE VIEW VIEW_TEMPLATES_DATA AS (SELECT
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID     AS HEAD_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.NARRATION,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ID     AS LEG_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID,
   TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.AMOUNT,
   ACCOUNTS.CURRENCY_ID,
   IS_PAYER
FROM  TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS
      LEFT OUTER JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.HEAD_TABLE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID
      LEFT OUTER JOIN ACCOUNTS ON TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS.ACCOUNT_ID = ACCOUNTS.ID
      JOIN (SELECT TEMPLATE_ID, (CASE WHEN PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID IS NOT NULL THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END) AS IS_PAYER
              FROM (SELECT TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID AS TEMPLATE_ID, ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID AS PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID
                      FROM ACCOUNTS
                           RIGHT JOIN TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS ON ACCOUNTS.PAYER_TEMPLATE_ID =TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID))
      ON TEMPLATE_ID = TEMPLATE_TRANSACTIONS.ID
);
```

When you put the first `LEFT OUTER JOIN` between parentheses, the joined table `TEMPLATE_TRANSACTION_LEGS` is not visible from the second `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: Perfect!!  Thank you so much!!  I will remember this, I couldn't figure out why it wasn't visible since it's clearly there, but now I see.  Awesomely clear explanation too, thanks again.